# vector manipulation in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD of the form

```
res73: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Vector[(Long, Int)], Vector[(Long, Int)])] = MapPartitionsRDD[72]
```

with many entries. Now i want to convert this RDD to another of the form below.

```
RDD[(Long,Long),(Int,Int)]
```

An entry of original RDD could be of the form

```
((2,3),(5,7)) -> (4,8)
```

which should become

```
(2,4) -> (3,8)
(5,4) -> (7,8)
```

in new RDD. This should happen for each entry of original RDD.

**Another example:**

```
(1,2) -> ((3,4),(5,6))
```

becomes

```
(1,3) -> (2,4)
(1,5) -> (2,6)
```

I am unable to code it in scala. Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```scala
val input: RDD[(Vector[(Long, Int)], Vector[(Long, Int)])] = ...

val result: RDD[Vector[((Long, Long), (Int, Int))]] = input.map {
  case (left, right) =>
    for ((ll, li) <- left; (rl, ri) <- right) yield {
      (ll, rl) -> (li, ri)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah it works. Thanks. But one thing. The input entry (1,2) -> ((3,4),(5,6))   becomes Vector[((1,3),(2,4)),((1,5),(2,6))]. Now how do I change the code    to get Vector[((1,3),(2,4))] and Vector[((1,5),(2,6))] as two separate entries in the result.

Comment: @CRM you have to replace the line `(ll, rl) -> (li, ri)` with `Vector((ll, rl) -> (li, ri))`.

Comment: Getting the following compilation error on the 'for' loop line : type mismatch;  found   : scala.collection.immutable.Vector[scala.collection.immutable.Vector[((Long, Long), (Int, Int))]]  required: Vector[((Long, Long), (Int, Int))]

Comment: I was looking for the resultant RDD of the form RDD[(Long,Long),(Int,Int)] so that I can aggregate by key later

Comment: using flatMap helped fix that

Comment: With the above code, I am having memory overflow errors when large datasets are input. I think combining values of duplicate keys at this step itself will save some memory. Is there a way I can achieve that?